# Paper.js zigzag path

Tags: paperjs

Im using paper.js and attempting to created function to create zizag paths. I have divided the path up in to segments, using getPointAt and now trying ad the zigzag by adding the normals
[sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/RZFPawMhEMW/igiF3Wa7leSWRErpvRR6jDkYd3Yja8aiJoGGfPf6r+1JffObN/q8UZQnoGv6OUNQR9pRZYd0vkhHvuXECcKVfMhwbFqBSfRBulBlqzE0Fw3XXgEGcBUBHHjhejkMzYqxbslYLEbDrORal7gq+uDsDG/WWMcFPRipZkEFFjtlzxgnLllHDOAUjjzdrC/7jcDRuiZxmhO2IXqb+bhZLNqbQJJKdhw9RA9NnosdeaxeFUDrTtIU4wnCez6+hqY0thFfsYj+PqBiOYB/qq2Eh+kU8/A7ve+/EpJ79MOSc/ZSJq2fyhpblEVvDfTGTs2fSATeazRgQAWIiQZ3hpQJib90cCDn7O3pere//wA=) and code. Thanks in advance
code:

```
var zag= new Path()
var start= new Point(view.center)
var end= start.add(300,200)
zag.add(start, end)
zag.strokeColor="black"

var count= 20, length= zag.length;
for(var i= 0; i<count; i++){
 var offset= i / count * length
 var normal= zag.getNormalAt(offset) * 30
 zag.add(zag.getPointAt(offset))
 zag.segments[i].point.add(i%2==0?normal:-normal)
console.log(normal)
 
}
zag.selected= true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use another path than the original one to build your zigzag because you are mutating it and this might alter the points/normals calculations.
Here is a corrected [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/ZVJRT8IwEP4rzRLDJjgbeDHDhaivxpj4pvhQutuoKy1pC0SB/+61ZbJgX3bX77vvvrt1nyi2gqRI3lpwfJmMEq4rn3OtrCNSKCAlUbAjr8wt02w6N3MVMeuYcR2ohXLpVsAu56AcmD4RVIW0QM9ZVaUTSkdkTGnk+BbhOhBGnt0DrDO6hScttUGNwUIy3g4CfNb/Ec07a/7bjPe5BQncgffgzAYuirneKD/FGD1JUI1bYhJaxyzQa+yeSnBEIEin+LkvYyXGw2FG9p5F8ERRXdcWvKogt6cO16Snd2YqbVZMBmZZojY5HE5hKOvI/sx6m0azNOuDRfTcgHsJig8ujSYy7DyhF13XXqSbE2uC6Lkk/A5BrsiYBE+zzmZBbmKU/QmeluwrgmpEjt2S10Z/4fZzxp3YwjP7BpPXwj3icJWND2YR4txyJiGl+V0WJfApLgywNqjapPj4PP4C) which you should easily be able to adapt to your use case.

```
const line = new Path();
const start = new Point(view.center);
const end = start.add(300, 200);
line.add(start, end);
line.strokeColor = 'black';

const zigZag = new Path();
zigZag.selected = true;

const count = 20, length = line.length;
for (let i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    const offset = i / count * length;
    const normal = i === 0 || i === count
        ? new Point(0, 0)
        : line.getNormalAt(offset) * 30;
    const point = line.getPointAt(offset).add(i % 2 == 0 ? normal : -normal);
    zigZag.add(point);
}

project.activeLayer.fitBounds(view.bounds.scale(0.8));
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Should I set the reference path to hide?

Comment: sure, or you can even remove it once your zigzag path is done depending on your use case