# ZigZag path onMouseDrag with paper.js

Tags: paperjs

Hi im tryign to create a zigzag path using Path.js's onMouseDrag function but getting in to a bit of a muddle [here is a sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/dVJBasMwEPzKYijYJDUmtxrUXtJjoVB6inNQ5Y0t4uwaS05Kgv9e2XIITh2dRjurmdFKl4DkAYM0+NqjVWWwDBTn/f4oG6ilLTPq0VkXZ1l4XCEV17rilqyHOVZWis02I8tcxTv9i/laGytJoYBVktGuJWU1EzB9cGtwzScK8Yhko0tG4FZvKIDwBJ8OhdGtGss8971xzdqd8JTPNT3SZTTj1chi6uXFhtSwEPCSzJoN/Gg24LhuTXlHzjp+11M/PzbhDQwWB8eZ+DrMR5e51R9MQDEZrjCuuAj/h91x8y5VGYa9CCxBRyBeYUx0p63hCVYgBCTwNrQv3KtBOsBnB0fhbprKYIXKYi7ANi2Os8jIfaSfBuV+iGqCdLPt/gA=)

and code

```
var path
var zigzag
var length
var count
var delta=[]
tool.fixedDistance= 20
function onMouseDown(event){
    path= new Path()
    path.add(event.point)
    zigzag= new Path()
}

function onMouseDrag(event){
    event.delta += 90
    path.add(event.delta)
    delta.push(event.delta)
}

function onMouseUp(event){
    length= path.segments.length
    zigzag= new Path()
    zigzag.add(event.point)
    console.log(delta)
    delta.forEach(( zig , i) => {
        zigzag.add(i % 2 == 0 ? zig + 20 : zig - 20)
    })
    zigzag.selected= true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65807206/7615922), here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating a possible way to do it.

```
let line;
let zigZag;

function onMouseDown(event) {
    line = new Path({
        segments: [event.point, event.point],
        strokeColor: 'black'
    });
    zigZag = createZigZagFromLine(line);
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {
    line.lastSegment.point = event.point;
    if (zigZag) {
        zigZag.remove();
    }
    zigZag = createZigZagFromLine(line);
}

function createZigZagFromLine(line) {
    const zigZag = new Path({ selected: true });

    const count = 20, length = line.length;
    for (let i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        const offset = i / count * length;
        const normal = i === 0 || i === count
            ? new Point(0, 0)
            : line.getNormalAt(offset) * 30;
        const point = line.getPointAt(offset).add(i % 2 == 0 ? normal
            : -normal);
        zigZag.add(point);
    }

    return zigZag;
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic, I wish I understood, I feel like Merlin's apprentice at the moment :) Not sure why the zigZag is removed onMouseDrag? I don't suppose we could go through the code over a video chat using Codepens peer coding or something similar?

Comment: I did get something going on codepen ut ti was a mess and there are random points without Zigs or Zags https://codepen.io/limitedunlimited/pen/BaLgjjj